# Angular 4 (ejected) and E2E tests (Protractor/Selenium configuration)

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, protractor

I'm trying to run E2E tests via Protractor/Selenium on an ejected Angular 4 project.

My `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet node",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js"
}
...
```

My `protractor.conf`:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: true,
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    specs: [
        './src/e2e/**/*.e2e-test.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
            spec: {
                displayStacktrace: true
            }
        }));

        browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
    }
};
```

When running `npm run e2e` Chrome boots up, but it's trying to open `data:text/html,<html></html>` for every test, and then shuts down quickly. What am I missing? I tried adding `baseUrl` to my `protractor.conf`, but it doesn't help, as it seems that Selenium is not even running.

Comment: did you forget to specify your application `baseUrl` ?

Comment: Where is it running? :)

Comment: You have to specify that in your `conf` file. see this conf file for example- https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript/blob/master/config/config.ts#L9

Comment: That's a great example :) Seriously, I don't know what I should specify there? Where is Selenium running? If I specify `http://localhost:4444` it doesn't work.

Comment: You should either use `seleniumAddress` or `directConnect` in your config but not both. You see when you give selenium address it runs the selenium server locally in your system. For that you would need a selenium server installed separately but if you use `directConnect`, you don't need to install selenium server, it would directly launch the browser. Give your application url in `baseUrl` and use `directConnect` for now and see!. Please refer this link for more info - http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup

Comment: I understand. But again, what is the `baseUrl`? Where is the application running? I have build it, it lives statically in the `dist` directory, and that's all. Where is the server? That's why I *need* Selenium, right?

Comment: `baseUrl` is your application url. Without that how will you run your test scripts?

Comment: I want to run this on deploy. It's an ejected Angular 4 project, which means I only have `package.json` and `"postinstall": "npm run build -aot --target=production --environment=prod && npm run test && npm run e2e"`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem. I somehow needed to run `ng serve`, which can now, because the project was ejected, be run via `npm run start`. This is a Travis CI deployment (which I highly recommend), so see the `before_script`:

```
before_script:
    - nohup npm run start &
script:
    - npm run build -aot --target=production --environment=prod
    - npm run test
    - npm run e2e
```

Final `package.json` (remains default after `ng eject`):

```
...
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build -aot --target=production --environment=prod"
}
...
```

Final `protractor.conf` (remains default after `ng eject`):

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './src/e2e/**/*.e2e-test.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
    },
    onPrepare() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
            spec: {
                displayStacktrace: true
            }
        }));
    }
};
```

Here's what happens when you `ng eject`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6171.

Two and a half days waisted. Thank you Angular CLI team for this bug, truly, thank you.

Comment: thanks for posting your solution. This also cost me a number of days. Pretty aggravating!